# PHP When i press the login button nothing happen

Tags: php

I was trying to create a login page, but it doesn't seem to work. When I enter details and click login. Nothing happens. I try to login again, still nothing happens. I want to happen is when i login a popup window will appear and i will be directed to the homepage

```
<?php 


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onlineshop");

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<div class = "boxlog1"

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"class="username" required />
        <input type="text" name="lpass" placeholder="Password" class="passwordl" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="log" name="log"/>
    </form>

<a href="forget.php"><p class="forget">Forget password</p></a>
</div>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['log'])){

        $c_email = $_POST['uname'];
        $c_pass = $_POST['lpass'];

        $sel_c = "select * from customers where customer_pass='$c_pass' AND customer_email='$c_email'";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $sel_c);
        $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c);

        if($check_customer == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Password or Email is incorrect!')</script>";
        exit();
        }
else{
                $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
                echo "<script>alert('login!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('paymnet.php','_self')</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be starting a session with `session_start();` first. You also need to look up how to prevent SQLi.

Comment: I already put session_start(); and still nothing happens

Comment: I seriously recommend using a separate script for the logon processing. Ie, don't use a form that submits to itself. You will get all kinds of `Confirm form re submission` errors. Don't you want your password to be `type="password"`? Is your `else` code being run?

Comment: Does the page not try load another on click? Does nothing show on the screen? A bit more detail would be nice.

Comment: Nothing happens, when i click the login button it shows the same form

Comment: Try closing the unclosed `div` tag `<div class = "boxlog1"` to `<div class = "boxlog1">`

Comment: the div is already close in the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the page to the form action

For example:

```
<form action"login.php">
```

Or use

```
<form action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

And close your div tag with '`>`', so

```
<div class="boxlog1">
```

Working example

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onlineshop");

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<div class="boxlog1">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"class="username" required />
        <input type="text" name="lpass" placeholder="Password" class="passwordl" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="log" name="log"/>
    </form>
<a href="forget.php"><p class="forget">Forget password</p></a>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['log'])){

        $c_email = $_POST['uname'];
        $c_pass = $_POST['lpass'];

        $sel_c = "select * from customers where customer_pass='$c_pass' AND customer_email='$c_email'";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $sel_c);
        $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c);

        if($check_customer == 0){

        echo "<script>alert('Password or Email is incorrect!')</script>";
        exit();

        } else {
                $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
                echo "<script>alert('login!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('paymnet.php','_self')</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

And here with updated security against SQL Injection. Dont forget to encrypt your password so it cannot be stolen

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onlineshop");

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<div class="boxlog1">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"class="username" required />
        <input type="text" name="lpass" placeholder="Password" class="passwordl" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="log" name="log"/>
    </form>
<a href="forget.php"><p class="forget">Forget password</p></a>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['log']) && isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['lpass'])){

        $c_email = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($_POST['uname']));
        $c_pass = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lpass']));

        $sel_c = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_pass=UNHEX('$c_pass') AND customer_email=UNHEX('$c_email')";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $sel_c);
        $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c);

        if($check_customer === 0){

        echo "<script>alert('Password or Email is incorrect!')</script>";
        exit();

        } else {
                $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
                echo "<script>alert('login!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('paymnet.php','_self')</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

I did'nt changed really much. Just closed your div tag correctly and added an action. However, it does work without the action filled in.

Comment: action="" is self submission which is what he wants. I do not recommend it though.

Comment: when i add the page to the form action, it loads to that page but the php script still not working, and i already close the div tag and nothing happens too

Comment: thanks, can you tell me what did you change to run the code properly?